# Do Jersey client support NTLM proxy

Tags: java, http, ntlm, jersey-client, proxy-authentication

I'm trying to make a jersey client call using NTLM proxy? is that possible as i was not able to get any clear information on the same. Did anyone tried before?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible to configure the [Jersey Client](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/user-guide.html#client) to connect through a proxy server that requires NTLM authentication.

Here is a simplified code snippet that prepares a suitable `ClientConfig` that should work with Jersey v2.5+:

```
final ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();

config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, "http://myproxy.com:8000");

CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

final AuthScope ntlmAuthScope =
        new AuthScope("myproxy.com", 8000, AuthScope.ANY_REALM, "NTLM");

credentialsProvider.setCredentials(
        ntlmAuthScope,
        new NTCredentials("user", "password", "hostname", "domain") );

config.property(
        ApacheClientProperties.CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER, credentialsProvider);

config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(config);
```

Please note: I am using the Apache HttpClient connector with Jersey Client - you may require slightly different code if you are using [another client transport connector](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.7/user-guide.html#d0e4419).

You may also need to add the following line to your code if you want your POST/PUT requests to be buffered (and therefore repeatable) in response to any 407 authentication challenges that come back from your proxy server:

```
config.property(ClientProperties.REQUEST_ENTITY_PROCESSING,
                RequestEntityProcessing.BUFFERED);
```

Comment: I tried the suggested solution but if I do a post of the form:

client.target(...).request().post(...)

no "Authorization" header gets attached to my request. Am I doing something wrong?